# How can I use sscanf to analyze string data?

Tags: c, string, format

How do I split a string into two strings (array name, index number) only if the string is matching the following string structure: "ArrayName[index]".
The array name can be 31 characters at most and the index 3 at most.

I found the following example which suppose to work with "Matrix[index1][index2]". I really couldn't understand how it does it in order to take apart the part I need to get my strings.

```
sscanf(inputString, "%32[^[]%*[[]%3[^]]%*[^[]%*[[]%3[^]]", matrixName, index1,index2) == 3
```

This try over here wasn't a success, what am I missing?

```
sscanf(inputString, "%32[^[]%*[[]%3[^]]", arrayName, index) == 2
```

Comment: The original code isn't reading integers, even though the variables are named `index1` and `index2`. It's reading 3 strings. It's confusing because the characters `[` and `]` being filtered out are themselves part of the syntax. Split the format string at each `%` and figure out what each part is doing.

Comment: ...and note that the text `index1` and `index2` (and `index` in yours) are all truncated to the string `"ind"` by the `3` in the format spec.

Comment: I just don't get how the format expression works, seems to be different from regex and couldn't find good documentation for it.

Comment: The `scanf` function family is not simple. I suggest spending an hour with the man [pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/sscanf-sscanf-l-swscanf-swscanf-l?view=vs-2017) (perhaps a [separate page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-fields-scanf-and-wscanf-functions?view=vs-2017)  for  for [each aspect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/scanf-type-field-characters?view=vs-2017) of the function) and looking at examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I split a string into two strings (array name, index number) only if the string is matching the following string structure: "ArrayName[index]".

With `sscanf`, you don't.  Not if you mean that you can rely on nothing being modified in the event that the input does not match the pattern.  This is because `sscanf`, like the rest of the `scanf` family, processes its input and format linearly, without backtracking, and by design it fills input fields as they are successfully matched.  Thus, if you scan with a format that assigns multiple fields or has trailing literal characters then it is possible for results to be stored for some fields despite a matching failure occurring.

But if that's ok with you then [@gsamaras's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57400671/2402272) provides a nearly-correct approach to parsing and validating a string according to your specified format, using `sscanf`.  That answer also presents a nice explanation of the meaning of the format string.  The problem with it is that it provides no way to distinguish between the input fully matching the format and the input failing to match at the final `]`, or including additional characters after.

Here is a variation on that code that accounts for those tail-end issues, too:

```
  char array_name[32] = {0}, idx[4] = {0}, c = 0;
  int n;

  if (sscanf(str, "%31[^[][%3[^]]%c%n", array_name, idx, &c, &n) >= 3
          && c == ']' && str[n] == '\0')
    printf("arrayName = %s\nindex = %s\n", array_name, idx);
  else
    printf("Not in the expected format \"ArrayName[idx]\"\n");
```

The difference in the format is the replacement of the literal terminating `]` with a `%c` directive, which matches any one character, and the addition of a %n directive, which causes the number of characters of input read so far to be stored, without itself consuming any input.

With that, if the return value is at least 3 then we know that the whole format was matched (a `%n` never produces a matching failure, but docs are unclear and behavior is inconsistent on whether it contributes to the returned field count).  In that event, we examine variable `c` to determine whether there was a closing `]` where we expected to find one, and we use the character count recorded in `n` to verify that all characters of the string were parsed (so that `str[n]` refers to a string terminator).

You may at this point be wondering at how complicated and cryptic that all is.  And you would be right to do so.  Parsing structured input is a complicated and tricky proposition, for one thing, but also the `scanf` family functions are pretty difficult to use.  You would be better off with a [regex](https://linux.die.net/man/3/regex) matcher for cases like yours, or maybe with a machine-generated lexical analyzer (see [lex](https://linux.die.net/man/1/lex)), possibly augmented by machine-generated parser (see [yacc](https://linux.die.net/man/1/yacc)).  Even a hand-written parser that works through the input string with string functions and character comparisons might be an improvement.  It's still complicated any way around, but those tools can at least make it less cryptic.

***Note***: the above assumes that the index can be any string of up to three characters.  If you meant that it must be numeric, perhaps specifically a decimal number, perhaps specifically non-negative, then the format can be adjusted to serve that purpose.

Comment: *You may at this point be wondering at how complicated and cryptic that all is...*  Hear, hear.  *If* you're doing something dirt-simple and *if* you don't care about error handling and *if* you're still learning C and don't know any better, one of the `scanf` functions might be an adequate tool for the job, for now.  But if you're doing anything at all complicated... forget it.

Answer (score 0):

A naive example to get you started:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char str[] = "myArray[123]";
  char array_name[32] = {0}, idx[4] = {0};

  if(sscanf(str, "%31[^[][%3[^]]]", array_name, idx) == 2)
    printf("arrayName = %s\nindex = %s\n", array_name, idx);
  else
    printf("Not in the expected format \"ArrayName[idx]\"\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
arrayName = myArray
index = 123
```

which will find easy not-in-the-expected format cases, such as "ArrayNameidx]" and "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP[idx]", but not "ArrayName[idx".

The essence of [`sscanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) is to tell it where to stop, otherwise `%s` would read until the next whitespace.

This negated scanset `%[^[]` means read until you find an opening bracket.

This negated scanset `%[^]]` means read until you find a closing bracket.

Note: I used 31 and 3 as the width specifiers respectively, since we want to reserve the last slot for the NULL terminator, since the name of the array is assumed to be 31 characters at the most, and the index 3 at the most. The size of the array for its token is the max allowed length, plus one.

Comment: This fails to detect the error case in which the closing `]` is omitted.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't pass pretty simple tests.

Comment: @JohnBollinger that's exactly the case I am mentioning in my answer.  As I mentioned this is a naive example, to get people into it..

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use sscanf to analyze string data?

Use `"%n"` to detect a completed scan.

---

> array name can be 31 characters at most and the index 3 at most.

For illustration, let us assume the index needs to limit to a numeric value [0 - 999].

Use string literal concatenation to present the format more clearly.

```
char name[32];  // array name can be 31 characters
#define NAME_FMT "%31[^[]"
char idx[4];   // 
#define IDX_FMT "%3[0-9]"

int n = 0;  // be sure to initialize
sscanf(str,  NAME_FMT "[" IDX_FMT "]" "%n", array_name, idx, &n);

// Did scan complete (is `n` non-zero) with no extra text?
if (n && str[n] == '\0') {
  printf("arrayName = %s\nindex = %d\n", array_name, atoi(idx));
} else {
  printf("Not in the expected format \"ArrayName[idx]\"\n");
}
```